# How to append at the top/start in ImGuiTextBuffer instead of bottom/end

Tags: c++, imgui

I'm using an `ImGuiTextBuffer` in ImGui to store a text buffer for my program logs.

To append text, I'm using this method:

```
bot_log.appendf((text + "\n").c_str());
```

This is more or less how it looks in my GUI:

[image]

So my idea is to see in reverse order:

```
File ./waypoints/gstomb.txt Loaded!

Bot loaded correctly.
```

How can I append to the top/start instead of the bottom/end of the buffer?